# How to get value from multiple buttons and set it on multiple edittext -Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 4 Edittext and 11 buttons. I want to use those 11 buttons to display different text on edittext.
I did try carat.setText(carat.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText()); but it puts same value on all the 4 edittext.
i have 4 edittext named carat,price,total, list and i want to use those buttons to insert value into them.

If i use list.setText(list.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText()); total.setText(total.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText()); in the last line then when i enter value using buttons then same value gets enter in all the edittext at same time. But i don't want that. i want to enter the value in each edittext individually.

```
EditText carat,list,price,total;
Button submit;
Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, cancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    carat=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.carat);
    list=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.list);
    price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
    total=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.total);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
    seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
    zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
    cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);

    Spinner shape2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.shape2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter11 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.shape2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter11.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    shape2.setAdapter(adapter11);

    Spinner cut3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cut3);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter12 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cut3, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter12.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    cut3.setAdapter(adapter12);

    Spinner color=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter13 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter13.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    color.setAdapter(adapter13);

    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
    four.setOnClickListener(this);
    five.setOnClickListener(this);
    six.setOnClickListener(this);
    seven.setOnClickListener(this);
    eight.setOnClickListener(this);
    nine.setOnClickListener(this);
    zero.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    carat.setText(carat.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText());
    list.setText(list.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText());
    total.setText(total.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText());
}
```

Comment: its quite confusing .. whats ur expectation?

Comment: His expectation is that the text of the button he clicks is appended to the text that is already in the `carat` textview

Comment: In that case the code looks good

Comment: your code is doing what it supposed to do. but it is not setting other edittexts. how come you are saying that it is populating others with the same value?

Comment: If i use 
list.setText(list.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText());
total.setText(total.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText());

in the last line then when i enter value using buttons then same value gets enter in all the edittext at same time. But i don't want that. i want to enter the value in each edittext individually.